# How do I create a lit of unique/distinct IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a SQL code that has 3 columns. (1) UUID (2) timestamp 1 (3) timestamp 2 . I am trying to create a list which takes unique UUIDs and the first occurrence of timestamp 1. I used the distinct function but its not working. Can someone help understanding whats the right code.

Thanks

```
with raw_data as ( select UUID, cast(datestring as timetamp) as date1 date2 from XYZ )

    Select distinct UUID, date1, date2
    from raw_data
```

raw_data is

---

### ID #### Date1 (string) #### date2 (timestamp)

1. ```
     2021-07-05          2012-07-05
   ```
2. ```
     2021-07-05           2012-12-12
   ```
3. ```
      2021-07-12             2018-04-07
   ```
4. ```
      2021-07-19              2012-12-12
   ```

---

Desired output is

1. 2021-07-05.      2012-07-05
2. 2021-07-05      2012-12-12
3. 2021-07-12        2018-04-07

Comment: Can you please add examples of data and expected results and code that you have tried?

Comment: I'd like to. But this is internal company data. My raw data is has 3 cols. (1) UUID (2) Timestamp 1 (3) Timestamp 2. I applied a distinct command on UUID but I am still getting the same raw data

Comment: I heavily doubt that bunch of UUIDs and timestamps is something you can't share. You can slightly alter them if you want.

Comment: shared some sample code and output

Comment: Is Id #4 suppose to be `3` based on your expected results? or is your expected results suppose to include the row with id `4`?

Answer (score 0):

The following table uses a group by and the `MIN` to get the first occurrence of `timestamp1`.

```sql
SELECT
    UUID,
    MIN(timestamp1) as first_occurrence_of_timestamp_1
FROM
   mytable
GROUP BY
   UUID
```

#### Edit 1

In response to your timestamp conversion, I ran the following on hive and got the following results:

```sql
WITH XYZ AS (
    SELECT 1 as UUID, '2021-07-05' as datestring, '2012-07-05' as date2 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2021-07-05', '2012-12-12'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2021-07-12', '2018-04-07'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2021-07-19', '2012-12-12'
),
raw_data AS (
    SELECT
        UUID,
        CAST(datestring as TIMESTAMP) date1,
        date2
    FROM XYZ
)
SELECT
    UUID,
    MIN(date1) as first_occurrence_of_timestamp_1,
    MIN(date2) as earliest_date_2
FROM 
    raw_data
GROUP BY 
    UUID
```

Outputs:

| uuid | first_occurrence_of_timestamp_1 | earliest_date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-05 00:00:00.0 | 2012-07-05 |
| 2 | 2021-07-05 00:00:00.0 | 2012-12-12 |
| 3 | 2021-07-12 00:00:00.0 | 2012-12-12 |

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks for this! I did try the MIN () command. But it is giving me an output where I am getting unique UUID in col_1 but for col_2 I am just getting 1 output. The output is 200,000 unique rows of UUID for col_1 (which is expected) and 200,000 rows of only 1 date for col_2 while it should have actually been multiple dates

Comment: Also, to clarify. The timestamp is actually a string but I converted it into a timestamp using the cast(datestr as timestamp) code.

Comment: Another interesting thing happens, When i remove the datestr and I just do a simple distinct UUID. I get the right output. I am doing something wrong with this string --> timestamp conversion

Comment: Also, made an edit to the original question. Where I am sharing my code.

Comment: @bob I asked a follow up question based on your sample output and expected results. I also updated my answer with a reproducible example which I ran on hive pertaining to your timestamp conversion with the string, it works. The distinct on the other hand provides 2 rows for the records with `id`=`3`